# When should you use a title attribute versus a custom tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed that YouTube uses both custom tool tips AND title attributes. Is there a purpose for this or is it merely a relic of their old code? I was thinking maybe it was an SEO or accessibility issue but while doing some research I don't think that's the case.

Is there a valid reason to use one or the other?

Comment: Simple mistake, my bad :) do you know the reason?

Comment: This is not an answer because you already know the answer. It's always good to have a valid HTML structure for SEO and accessibility. Screen readers for example heavily rely on a good content structure. Also it's good to make sure that your site works properly even if JS fails or is turned off. Conclusion: ALWAYS make sure your HTML is valid and reasonable. Even if you use other methods which might overwrite it's functionality.

Comment: May be they have been using that for the good UI and also SEO is the reason i think.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne That's not true. [Source 1](https://mrwweb.com/the-title-attribute-and-why-its-almost-useless/), [Source 2](https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/)

Comment: @JohnCullen These articles seem to be a few years old. What part was not true? The screen reader one? My statement still stays: ALWAYS have a valid content structure underneath. You often can't control which software or device will read your HTML, so always prepare for that. Also screen readers and so on might adapt the title-attribute in the future, so why not go safe and just add it.

Comment: I took a look at youtubes titles and it seems like they just generate the custom title out of the native one for style and usability reasons. Which seems pretty logical: 1. use the native title, 2. if you need anything else use the native title as "source".

Comment: @TheFrozenOne I couldn't find the title attribute for some of the elements... for example, the navigation icons. I'll take your word for it though. That makes sense... I had thought it was accessibility but thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this? https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-wai-ig/2020JulSep/0038.html

Comment: Also read this: https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/